# Can a .NET Semaphore be shared between users on the same computer?

Tags: .net, shared-memory, semaphore

I need to restrict access to a shared resource between 2 users logged into Terminal Server sessions (Windows 2008 R2 x64). From my tests, it appears one user cannot see the named system Semaphore already created by another user.  If I try sharing a Semaphore within the same user account, that works.  Should I be able to share this across accounts?

Comment: To the downvoter - could you please explain why? I'd like to think this is a decent question. If you feel it needs improving, please tell me how - that would help me write better questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a global semaphore that's visible across sessions.  Prefix its name with `Global\`.

Comment: Thanks! Ugh, what lousy documentation, that this (crucial) info is buried in a totally unrelated doc.  Way to go, MS.